# Infinite do-while loop in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, do-while

This function `displayMenu()` is being called in Main under the condition `while(menuChoice != Q)`, but the function itself has an internal infinite loop.

Any help on why the loop in the display menu function is infinite would be great... I think it may be something to do with the `do-while` structure or the relational operator `!=` working improperly.

```
FUNCTION DISPLAYMENU:
char displayMenu()
{
// can be useful info during development
cout << "Entered function displayMenu..." << endl;

char whatToDo = '?';


do {
    //Display Menu Options
    cout <<"Upload a regional sales data file \tU" <<endl;
    cout <<"display details (All loaded data) \tA" <<endl;
    cout <<"list details for specific Order number \tO" <<endl;
    cout <<"display summary by Region \tR" <<endl;
    cout <<"display summary by print method \tM" <<endl;
    cout <<"Clear all data \tC" <<endl;
    cout <<"Quit \tQ" <<endl;
    cout <<"\nPlease Enter Your Menu Choice: " <<endl;
    cin >> whatToDo;
} while (whatToDo != 'U' ||
         whatToDo != 'A' ||
         whatToDo != 'O' ||
         whatToDo != 'R' ||
         whatToDo != 'M' ||
         whatToDo != 'C' ||
         whatToDo != 'Q');

// can be useful info during development
cout << "Returning " << whatToDo << " from displayMenu..." << endl;

return whatToDo;

} // END function displayMenu()


FUNCTION MAIN 
while (menuChoice != 'Q'){
    menuChoice = displayMenu();
}
```

Comment: Also keep an eye out for `cin >> whatToDo` failing. That will probably also result in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (whatToDo != 'U' ||
         whatToDo != 'A' ||
         whatToDo != 'O' ||
         whatToDo != 'R' ||
         whatToDo != 'M' ||
         whatToDo != 'C' ||
         whatToDo != 'Q');
```

No matter what `whatToDo` is, at least 6 of those conditions are `true` so you get an infinite loop.

What you want is to keep looping until one of the conditions is `false`.

You should use something like this instead :

```
while (whatToDo != 'U' &&
       whatToDo != 'A' &&
       whatToDo != 'O' &&
       whatToDo != 'R' &&
       whatToDo != 'M' &&
       whatToDo != 'C' &&
       whatToDo != 'Q');
```

Answer (score 1):

This condition can never result in "false", which of course results in an endless while-loop. And it is only part of your ORed condition.

```
whatToDo != 'U' || whatToDo != 'A'
```

It would require `whatToDo` to be at the same time identical to 'U'  and to 'A'.

What you probably want is

```
whatToDo != 'U' && whatToDo != 'A'
```

"as long as whatToDo is neither A nor U ..." according to the equivalence of

```
!A && !B
```

and

```
!(A || B)
```

the latter being the more obvious phrasing for "NOR".